# I need help finding out the p,d,q values for arima model using the acf and pacf

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

[image: The plot of data]

The acf and pacf of this data look like this.

[image]

After first differencing, the acf and pacf look like this. Does this mean that arima cannot be used to model the data, or should I do further differences?

[image: The acf and pacf for first difference]

How can I infer the values of p and q from this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, this time series just doesn't seem to be autocorrelated. Try auto-arima with the seasonal component on, but I don't think it's gonna be easy to model this dataset

Comment: @Fatafim, you must be talking about the differenced series, not the original series. Whether taking the first difference is justifiable in the first place is something to think about. Perhaps and AR(1) model would be a better alternative to differencing.

Comment: @RichardHardy auto-arima adjusts for stationarity by itself, so what is exactly the problem?

Comment: @Fatafim, the OP did not mention auto.arima. My comment was meant in light of that.

Comment: @RichardHardy yes, but I did in my first comment.

Comment: @Fatafim, how is that relevant? The OPs results were obtained without auto.arima. Your comment that the time series does not seem to be autocorrelated was literally wrong, so I pointed out that you must have meant the *differenced* series. And I still maintain that perhaps an AR(1) model would be a better alternative to differencing for this series.

Comment: @RichardHardy it's relevant because it was my suggestion about what to try. How exactly do you want to want to fit an AR(1) model to nonstationary data?

Comment: @Fatafim, I did not say I want to fit an AR(1) model to nonstationary data. That would be a misinterpretation of my statements. I am sorry, but it seems there is a difficulty in communication. To prevent any further misunderstandings, I will leave this discussion.